# HSQL Get Date and Time from TIMESTAMP

Tags: hsqldb

I have a HSQLDB table with some informations and where a timestamp is stored

I want to select informations from specific time periods like every information of october between 0am and 5pm.

I didn't found any function like mysql'ones  DATE(myfield) OR TIME(myfield) which would be perfect for what i want.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE DATE(myField) BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-30' 
AND TIME(myField) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
```

The only things i found are to use the functions YEAR(), DAYOFMONTH(), DAYOFYEAR(), HOUR() ANd MINUTE() but I was wondering if there aren't any other simpler solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for such specialised functions as HSQLDB supports the general CAST expression for this purpose

```
CAST(myField AS DATE)
CAST(myField AS TIME)
```

HSQLDB also supports automatic cast from DATE to TIMESTAMP. Therefore an optimised query that can use an index on the myField column should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myField BETWEEN DATE'2012-10-01' AND DATE'2012-10-30' 
AND CAST(myField AS TIME) BETWEEN TIME'00:00:00' AND TIME'17:00:00'
```